# Reproducing CouchDB 1.2.0 password hash function in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, erlang, couchdb

I have a simple setup with an app server backed on to CouchDB in which I'm using CouchDB's built-in user authentication for users of the app server. The app server can access the _users database and retrieve a user's doc.

I am trying to replicate the password hash function so I can validate a user's password in the app server without having to authenticate against CouchDB.

The CouchDB security spec states:

> The "password_sha" attribute is an hexadecimal representation of the SHA-1 hash computed over a string that matches the user password concatenated with a salt (ideally a random string). The salt attribute is the hexadecimal representation of the salt used to generate the user's password hash.
>
> Since CouchDB 1.2.0, the password_sha and salt fields are automatically created when a password field is present in the user document. When the user document is written, CouchDB checks for the existence of the password field and if it exists, it will generate a salt, hash the value of the password field and hash the concatenation of the password hash and the salt. It then writes the resulting password into the password_sha field and the salt into the salt field. The password` field is removed.

Relevant source code:

```
% Lines 72-74 of couch_httpd_auth.erl

UserSalt = couch_util:get_value(<<"salt">>, UserProps, <<>>),
PasswordHash = hash_password(?l2b(Pass), UserSalt),
ExpectedHash = couch_util:get_value(<<"password_sha">>, UserProps, nil),

% Lines 237-238 of couch_httpd_auth.erl

hash_password(Password, Salt) ->
    ?l2b(couch_util:to_hex(crypto:sha(<<Password/binary, Salt/binary>>))).
```

This is my attempt to replicate it with a test user that has a password of "password":

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class PasswordSpec extends Specification {

    "Password" should {
        "match" in {

            val password = "password"

            val hexEncodedPasswordHash = "0fed560a9928b50761ebec5aa97c815999e6def0"
            val hexEncodedSalt = "2ba345d5f2880fae25de9ec7a78d38ae"

            val charset = "UTF-8"
            val codec = new Hex(charset)

            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
            md.reset()
            md.update(password.getBytes(charset))
            md.update(codec.decode(hexEncodedSalt.getBytes(charset)))
            val hashBytes = md.digest()
            val hexEncodedHash = new String(codec.encode(hashBytes), charset)

            hexEncodedHash mustEqual(hexEncodedPasswordHash)

        }
    }
}
```

This test is failing and I've run out of ideas as to why.

Comment: I figured it out. The salt bytes do not need to be decoded from hex before being concatenated with the password bytes. I'll post this as answered in a few hours when stack lets me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The salt bytes do not need to be decoded from hex before being concatenated with the password bytes.